# require() of ES Module is not supported with typescript tests

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing

I'm trying to use typescript test runner to write tests. I use Typescript for my app and works it fine.

However when I'm trying to make tests, it fails with the error of `require() of ES Module is not supported with typescript tests` on line `import fetch from 'node-fetch';` which compiles into `const node_fetch_1 = __importDefault(require("node-fetch"));`

The same exact import works fine inside regular project .ts files. The error only appears in tests.

My TSConfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "nodenext",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "strict": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "paths": {
      "requests/*": ["./src/requests/*"],
      "test/*": ["./test/*"],
      "/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/", "test/", "src/requests", "./config.json", "./package.json"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

`type: module` in package.json is not an option for me, since it breaks everything else.

So, how do I make typescript to work with tests?